# Placemark name(label) not appearing in Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have a KML file with some locations, the problem is that the names are not displayed beside the placemark in Google Earth.
KML Part

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Schema name="feverlocs" id="feverlocs">
    <SimpleField name="block" type="string"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="lat" type="float"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="long" type="float"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
<Folder><name>feverlocs</name>
  <Placemark>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#feverlocs">
        <SimpleData name="block">Garhi</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="lat">29.598867</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="long">79.469856</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Point><coordinates>79.469856,29.598867</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#feverlocs">
        <SimpleData name="block">SodaSaroli</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="lat">30.278907</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="long">78.137521</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Point><coordinates>78.137521,30.278907</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
```

I am not able to understand the problem.
So basically SodaSaroli should appear on it's placemark

Answer (score 0):

Only the `<name>` field appears as a label on the map as defined in the KML. The [ExtendedData](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#extendeddata) elements would appear in the description balloon when a placemark is clicked unless you have an explicit [description](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#description_37) element.

The scope of the name is described in the [KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#feature).

If want name to appear then need to add `<name>` field to the placemarks:

```
 <Placemark>
    <name>SodaSaroli</name> ***
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#feverlocs">
        <SimpleData name="block">SodaSaroli</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="lat">30.278907</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="long">78.137521</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
    <Point><coordinates>78.137521,30.278907</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
```